# Do I need Magic Wisdom to defeat the Spectre in Pathfinder ACG?

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

In the *Pathfinder Adventure Card Game*, the `Spectre` monster card's check to defeat says:

```
Combat 11 OR Wisdom Divine 7
```

The card text says (in part):

```
If the check to defeat does not have the Magic trait, the Spectre is undefeated.
```

Does this mean that I must somehow magically augment my Wisdom to defeat the Spectre, or does that clause only apply to a Combat check?  Will my Wisdom only scare it away for a while, or can I defeat it permanently?  Is there any way to add the Magic trait to a Wisdom check?

I didn't find any mention of this in the errata, but maybe I didn't look hard enough.

Comment: As an aside, careful when you encounter the Siren. Defeating it actually IS a straight Wisdom check, no Magic trait required.

For a while my friends and I were defeating it with Combat checks until we started diligently paying attention to the monsters that came up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a way to augment a Wisdom check with the Magic trait, I'm unaware of it except with using Divine spells or items.

Weapons and/or spells with the Magic trait work for the Combat check.

Either way, you *cannot* use a straight Wisdom (or straight Divine) check to defeat a Spectre; as it's Incorporeal, it must be defeated by magical means.

Comment: There is the power of the cleric Kyra ("Add 1d8 with the Magic trait to your check to defeat a bane with the Undead trait.").